# UI Problem in Ubuntu after give update and run VLC player

Tags: 12.10, gnome, vlc, desktop-environments

I have Ubuntu 12.10 in my Lenovo G580 machin.I have given update to my system two days before VLC player and other applications are working fine till that date.After that update i can't run VLC player in my machine i can't see UI of VLC and my OS not performing regular actions,i mean it'll not show any applications close minimize buttons and it's not showing system menus.If i didn't run VLC then it's working fine.Can anyone help in this?

is this compatibility issue in new version of VLC?

Answer (score 0):

re install vlc

```
$ sudo apt-get purge vlc
```

or

```
$ sudo apt-get autoremove vlc
```

installing the stable version

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:djcj/vlc-stable
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install vlc
```

then reset the unity

```
$ setsid unity
```

if that didnt workout try to re-install the unity & the desktop

```
$ sudo apt-get autoremove ubuntu-desktop 
$ sudo apt-get autoremove unity 
$ sudo apt-get update 
$ sudo apt-get install unity
$ sudo apt-get install unity-2d 
$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop 
$ sudo shutdown -r
```